# Android: How can I retrieve ListView height and set ListView Items (cells) height depending on ListView Height?

Tags: android, listview

I have some class LoginActivity.java. In the onCreate method I retrieve ListView:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.snListView);
```

then:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In addition there are login.xml layout - there are:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/snListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

and sn_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"       
android:background="@drawable/listview_item_background"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
...
```

At the moment I have cell's height 100dp, I need that cell's height will depend on device, I mean I have here 5 cells showing at login screen in ListView and I need that these 5 rows will fit the ListView (cell's height = ListView's height/5).

Answer (score 0):

that cells should cover the entire screen?
In that case use a LinearLayout instead and add the Relative as child views, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon48x48_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon48x48_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon48x48_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon48x48_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon48x48_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: they should cover the entire list view that is 3/4 of full screen